# How to keep KDE Plasma Launcher Icon visible when running?

Tags: kde, plasma5, launcher

### Scenario

Using KDE Plasma 5 default launcher, when I add an application to the launcher it's icon will be present in the panel as expected.  When I click the icon the application will launch as expected.  The icon I clicked disappears but a new panel button for the running instance will appear.

### Question

How do I keep both the launcher icon, and keep the new panel button for the running instance on the panel such that nothing disappears?  I would like to start a second running instance of an application by clicking the launcher icon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your plasma workspace layout is locked, unlock it first: Right-click on desktop -> Unlock widgets.

Now open your application menu and right-click on the application you want to add a launcher for, then select `Add to Panel`:
[image]

You will now have a launcher which will launch a new instance each time you click on it and will stay there regardless of running instances.

That being said, personally I do use the Launcher icons that transform into an instance button in the task manager, but I configured the Task Manager to launch a new instance on middle-click:

[image]

Comment: Your answer works perfectly.  I wonder why some of my icons on my panel hide when the application is running.  I will convert them all using your method.  Thanks for the assistance!